# Bind exsiting DOM elements to view model

Tags: knockout.js

I want to display data from an array using knockoutjs and I could do that using the foreach binding like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <li data-bind="text: data1"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: data2"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: data3"></li>
</ul>
```

That would work fine but the problem is that it can only be done after the page is completely loaded and I don't like that because I can build the initial list on the server and this way it loads the data way faster. I would have something like this comming from the server:

```
<ul>
    <li>Data1 value</li>
    <li>Data2 value</li>
    <li>Data3 value</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to bind those list elements to a view model array?

Comment: "Is it possible?" - Yes but what is the difference?  It's not faster as you are still having to load data, you just perceive it as faster because you are probably loading up a bunch of scripts.  If you insist on doing it this way just use selectors to grab the elements and get their values and stuff them in an array after the page loads.

Comment: Wise words from @PWKad. Please avoid this, it's not the *knockout way*

Comment: Please don't have your server generate markup...

Comment: One of the many reasons to use Knockout is to move logic from the server to the client.  Say if you had 1000s of users.  Your server could easily process the data and markup with its 10s of CPUs or you could have the server only process the data and the CPUs of your 1000s of clients could process the markup.

Comment: The things that don't change when user is on page - do on server. Things that needs to be updated live, without refresh, the things you would insert with jQuery or any other framework - do this using knockout and AJAX call to your API.

Comment: While this might not be the ideal KO way, it is not an invalid ambition: there are some good reasons for rendering HTML on the server first, such as performance and SEO. The challenge will be to find a really nice way of doing it that works well with KO. I've put an answer below that shows a proof-of-concept, but there would be a long way to go to get a truly elegant and generic solution. I think there's an interesting project in that for someone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using jQuery to parse the list generated by the server, then populate the KO observableArray, then call applyBindings, which replaces the server list with a KO bound list.

http://jsfiddle.net/dLbc4/1/

---

**More info**

As commenters above have pointed out, this isn't the pure KO way of doing things. However, some JS frameworks do now pre-render the initial content on the server, then apply their bindings after the page has been displayed to the user. The reasons for this include:

- Performance - a fully-built page appears immediately
- SEO - a fully-built HTML doc is available for search engines
- Old browser / mobile support - these devices can use the prebuilt HTML page, albeit not do much with it

Examples of frameworks doing this:

- http://derbyjs.com/ with an http://expressjs.com/ server app
- https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr for Backbone apps

These allow server-rendered versions of your pages using the same codebase; ie, the same logic is used to create the HTML on both the server and the client.

Is this possible with KO? I don't see why not and there's perhaps an interesting project here to do this (or does someone know of a project already?). The same server-side DB could provide both a static HTML page and the actual data through an API for KO to render later on. The biggest challenge is the single code base problem, otherwise you end up with server-side logic (in PHP or Python or whatever) rendering HTML on the server, then JavaScript logic rendering HTML through KO on the client.

Here is a quick fiddle showing the concept in action with the HTML from the original question:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLbc4/1/

In this concept, you add all the KO bindings in the server HTML, apart from the actual data, which is pre-rendered by the server. To demo this I've added a simple example of adding new elements to the list. All the KO statements are there, apart from the 'text: $data' binding.

```
<ul class="preload" data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <li>Data1 value</li>
    <li>Data2 value</li>
    <li>Data3 value</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" name="new" data-bind="value: new_element">
<button data-bind="click: add_element">add</button>
```

So the page is 'complete' - ideal for SEO, performance, etc. Now we need some code to extract the data values and add them to a view-model. Here's my VM - it handles the list of elements and also a list of fruits, just to demonstrate some steps towards making this generic and not entirely hard-coded into supporting just a structure called 'elements':

```
AppViewModel = function() {
    // 'Elements' list suport
    this.elements = ko.observableArray();
    this.add_element = function(data, event) {
        this.elements.push(this.new_element());
    }
    this.new_element = ko.observable();

    // 'Fruits' list support
    this.fruits = ko.observableArray();
    this.add_fruit = function(data, event) {
        this.fruits.push(this.new_fruit());
    }
    this.new_fruit = ko.observable();
}
```

Finally, here's the code to replace the static HTML from the server with KO-rendered content, that is bound to the VM. You can check it has worked, because the 'add' buttons in the fiddle will add new elements or new fruits, respectively. The code is slightly generic, in that the same code handles the elements list and the fruits list. However, you can see that it assumes your list child element will always be a li - so some work needed there!

```
initKO = function() {
    // Start with an empty view model
    var app_vm = new AppViewModel();

    // Handle any list tagged with class="preload"
    $(".preload").each(function(i, el) {
        // Extract the data from the HTML and populate the view model
        var array_name = $(el).attr("data-bind").split(":")[1].trim();
        $(el).children().each(function(j, child) {
            app_vm[array_name].push($(child).text());    
        });

        // Empty the prebuilt static HTML
        $(el).empty();

        // Add a new node for binding
        $(el).append($("<li data-bind='text: $data'></li>"));
    });

    // Call applyBindings to rebuild the HTML via KO
    ko.applyBindings(app_vm);
}

// Do all this after document.ready. The page initially appears with the 
// server-provided static HTML. We then replace this HTML with a KO-rendered
// DOM.
$(document).ready(function() {
    initKO();
});
```

Comment: That works for me. Performance and old browser support are the main reasons that I wanted to do it this way. Thank you for the detailed answer and working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution from Erik Schierboom: https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/knockout-pre-rendered. It basically does what you are looking for